Gang of Children wearing masks terrorizes traveling family
Hoping someone can help me figure out the name of a horror movie, thanks in advance! I'm not sure but I would guess it's from around 2006, definitely before 2011. It was a family traveling in a car that gets lost (in Ireland I thought) and are terrorized by a group of children wearing really freaky masks.
Of course the family split up and begin to disappear and these freaky kids (maybe 7-10 yrs old) in white masks (if I'm remembering right almost porcelain doll style) are lurking around, beating sticks on the car etc. The protagonist, a young female, makes it to a cabin for help only to find out the whole community is involved. I think the kids were deformed, hence the masks, and in typical horror fashion the end reveal was they were looking to kidnap women for breeding stock. 
I must have watched it a few years ago on Netflix but now for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.  Is this ringing any bells?

Approximate year of release? How old were the kids exactly? Do you remember anything else about the plot?

I'm not sure but I would guess around 2006, definitely before 2011.  It's a family traveling on vacation and they get lost.  Of course they split up and begin to disappear and these freaky kids (maybe 7-10 yrs old) in white masks (if I'm remembering right almost porcelain doll style) are lurking around, beating sticks on the car etc. The protagonist, a young female, makes it to a cabin for help only to find out the whole community is involved. I think the kids were deformed, hence the masks, and in typical horror fashion the end reveal was they were looking to kidnap women for breeding stock.

Possibly Plague Town from 2008.

An American family visiting their Irish roots accidentally stumbles on a horde of bloodthirsty mutant children.

The kids wear white masks to hide their deformed faces; the family members are separated and killed one by one (the children also hit the mom with branches at some point). The daughter is more or less the hero and final girl. Here's the trailer (Warning: Slightly Gory)




That's it, thank you!!!!!!!  I googled away and couldn't find it, you're a lifesaver.  Off to make some creepy masks, thanks again!

@CoryG No problem. Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark it as 'solved'.
